# Model Validation Metric for correct count out of expected

Tags: accuracy, metric

I'm trying to figure out what a scheme is called - what is the accuracy metric for the number of true positives out of the top n items, listed descended by probability, where n is the expected # in the population?

For example, if we expect their to be 1000 true cases in a population, and we then put forth our top 1000 items scored by probability, and get 600 correct, the "accuracy" here is 60%.  What is this correct term for this "accuracy"?

(I'd want to call it "accuracy at expected inclusion" or something...)

Comment: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)
[Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)
[Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352)
The same problems apply to your KPI, and indeed to all evaluation metrics that rely on hard classifications. Instead, use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate these using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).

Comment: FWIW, I'm not advocating this method.. I just want to know if it has a name